# Sending encrypted razor password field to mvc4 controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, password-encryption

I have a razor field @Html.PasswordFor in my mvc4 view and one button that submits it among other user information:

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("StoreInfo", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
   {
      // stuff
      @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ViewModel.userPwd, new { id = "UserPwd" })

      // stuff
      <input id="submitInfo" type="submit" value="@Resource.ButtonSubmit" />
   }
```

What I want is to send the password encrypted within the model to the mvc4 controller. The controller is the responsible to store it in the database. Also I want encryption method to be irreversible, I mean, password cannot be decrypted. How to do this? I think password encryption should be done in the mvc4 view using some javascript or jquery method, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Don't encrypt client-side, encrypt on the server. If you want the password to be encrypted when it is sent over the wire, send it over https. Then on the server use a one-way encryption algorithm  like SHA.

One way to do this is using the .NET Membership Provider. You set it up in the web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
        connectionStringName="DbConnectionStringName"
        enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" 
        requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" 
        maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
        minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
        passwordCompatMode="Framework20" applicationName="MyAppName" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Then you create your users with the `System.Web.Security.Membership` class.

```
Membership.CreateUser(userName, password);
```

That method will one-way encrypt the password for you.

Comment: Could you provide a little example on how to do this  (using https), please? Using [RequireHttps] attribute for the action in my controller which receives that information? Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: But if modifying the web.config it applies https to the entire website. I would like to use only https for a concrete mvc4 view and only when sending this info. Maybe using [RequireHttps] attribute in the controller's action is enough?

Comment: Yes, you can keep regular http on the site and only require https on the action methods where you need to apply data transfer encryption. However, you should require it on both the GET that returns your login form and the POST that accepts the login data from the user... using the `[RequireHttps]` attribute. Also, the above web.config entry does not add https for your site, it just encrypts the password on the server. Without https, the password could still be sent as plain text before it arrives at the server.

Comment: My mvc4 view is not a login page, it only contains user information and a critical field that is the password. Then I only want to encrypt this file when sending it to the controller.